Append arguments to a string with a do/while
I have a situation where I have an amount of arguments and a argument of how many arguments there are.
Like this: argument "list.itemsCount" is an int and says how many arguments of "item.#" (with the # being replaced by the number, 0 for the first argument, 1 for the second and so on. I want that for each argument "item.#", the value of that argument gets appended to one large string, starting either with an empty one or with one that already exists and has text.
In the end, it should say (if we have 4 arguments) something like this: "The following items are on that shopping list: flour, milk, egg, yeast
using System;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        string itemList = "The following items are on that shopping list:";
        int i = 0;
        int ic = Convert.ToInt32(args["list.itemsCount"]);
        do
        {
            itemList = + ", " + args[$"item.{i}"].ToString();
            i++;
        }
        while (i <= ic);
        return true;
    }
}

This is the code I thought of (or something similar), but it says:
(12,15): error CS0023: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operand of type 'string'
Am I doing it wrong? I know that there will be a comma and space before the first one, but let's ignore that for now, I'll come up with a solution for that one later.

You want += not =+ '+=' is shorthand for itemList = itemList + ', " + ....
For building a string like that you are better off using a StringBuilder, or even string.Join.
public bool Execute()
{
    StringBuilder itemList = new StringBuilder("The following items are on that shopping list:");
    int i = 0;
    int ic = Convert.ToInt32(args["list.itemsCount"]);
    do
    {
        itemList.Append(", " + args[$"item.{i}"].ToString());
        i++;
    }
    while (i <= ic);
    return true;
}

Though this would put a leading comma in your list. That could be catered for with:
   if (i > 0)
       itemList.Append(", ");

   itemList.Append(args[$"item.{i}"].ToString());

If you can build a set of argument values (Like a List<string> or array) then it can be converted to a string with string.Join:
List<string> itemArgs = new List<string>(ic);
while (i <= ic)
{
    itemArgs.Add(args[$"item.{i}"].ToString());
    i++;
}
string itemList = $"The following items are on that shopping list: {string.Join(", ", itemArgs)}";

Either approach, the code needs some validation for asserting whether these "item.#" arguments are actually found or not. There are some dangerous assumptions about the arguments and counts. Rather than sending a count and then parsing items, I would look at all arguments available and extract out all that match the "item.#" pattern, getting a count of matches and iterating through those.
